# GitPython List all commits for a specific file

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am writing a Python script and there I need to know all commits for a specific file. In my code I use [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) for other tasks but for this problem I can't find something.

In cmd line I use:

```
git log --pretty='%H' file-path
```

Answer (score 6):

You can query the commits on the 'repo' that you cloned:

```
commits = repo.iter_commits('--all', max_count=100, since='10.days.ago', paths=path)
```

...whereby '-all' will return commits on all branches and tags, and path is your filename.

And to use the commits you go like:

```
for commit in commits:
  print("Committed by %s on %s with sha %s" % (commit.committer.name, time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M", time.localtime(commit.committed_date)), commit.hexsha))
```

Answer (score 2):

What we are looking for in Git is:

```
git log --follow filename
```

not sure GitPython has it tho.

Comment: GitPython is a wrapper on top of Git tools, so it allows to specify almost anything supported by Git tools.