# how to get the file author with gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

If I have a specific file and wants get the last committer, how can I do this with gitpython ?

The repo is defined with `repo= git.Repo('.')`
but there is no function like `repo.commit(filename)`

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: how to get the last commiter of an file with gitpython

Comment: did you mean last commit author?

Comment: yes of this specific file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitPython List all commits for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723521/gitpython-list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file)