# Getting all commits for specific local file in git repo

Tags: python, gitpython

I have a python script where I am iterating through all python files in a local git repo, and doing some operations on these files:

```
for file in Path(rootDir).rglob("*.py"):
    # some operations
```

Now, I for every file that I perform some operations on, I would like to get all the commits that have made changes to that file.

In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723521/gitpython-list-all-commits-for-a-specific-file) This solution has been used with Gitpython:

```
for commit in commits:
  print("Committed by %s on %s with sha %s" % (commit.committer.name, time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M", time.localtime(commit.committed_date)), commit.hexsha))
```

But this is not really an option for me, I really need to be able to get all the commits for a specific file, using it's path.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you want to use `gitpython` or not?  What you're asking for is `git log xxx.txt`, with perhaps some formatting options just to return the commit id.

Comment: gitpython would be fine. I a bit unsure what the ´git log xxx.txt´ command means and should do? I would like to access all commits for a file programmatically

Comment: as long as I can have the filepath, and get the commits for that file

Comment: Have you used git much?  If you go to a command line and type `git log xxx.txt`, it shows you all the commits for that file, plus the log messages, which apparently you don't need.

Comment: yes, but using this inside my pytohn file, in the settings that i have described is the challenge

Comment: Like, I need the commits  as some kind of ojbect in python so that I can access it's fields

Answer (score 1):

Using pydriller, I was able to come up with a extremely inefficient solution.
Nonetheless, it does what it should in terms of accessing modifications made to a specific file

```
from pydriller import RepositoryMining

filepath ="/home/ask/Git/tweeda/Main.py"
filename = filepath.split('/')[-1]

linesChanged = 0 
linesdeleted = 0
linesAdded = 0

for commit in RepositoryMining("/home/ask/Git/tweeda", filepath=filepath).traverse_commits():
    # here you have the commit object


    for m in commit.modifications:
        if (filename == m.filename):
            linesdeleted = linesdeleted + m.removed
            linesAdded = linesAdded = m.added
            linesChanged = linesChanged = m.changed_methods # this is not correct, but how do I acces modified lines?


churn = linesChanged + linesAdded + linesdeleted

print(churn)
```